# Remove Unwanted files from PHP Composer Dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

How to remove unwanted files and folders from imported dependencies by composer?
(eg:example, test)

Comment: `composer update --no-dev`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no way to exclude files from dependencies yourself unless the original developer of the dependency supports this!

But some files/folders like `/docs` and `/tests` are excluded in the `.gitattributes` file of some projects when updating/installing from `dist`

There are two different sources where composer can get its data from when you composer install or composer update:

> **Dist:** The dist is a packaged version of the package data. Usually a released version, usually a stable release.
>
> **Source:** The source is used for development. This will usually originate from a source code repository, such as git. You can fetch this when you want to modify the downloaded package.
>
> Packages can supply either of these, or even both. Depending on certain factors, such as user-supplied options and stability of the package, one will be preferred.

If you make `dist` your preferred install in `composer.json`

```
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
},
```

then the files in `.gitattributes` of the dependencies are excluded. If a dependency doesn't make use of the `.gitattributes` the only thing you can do is to ask the developer of that dependency to include a `.gitattributes` file.

If you change from `source` to `dist` it can be that you need to remove the `vendor` folder and run `composer install` to make it redownloading from `dist`.

Comment: here's sample what you need to put `.gitattributes`:

https://github.com/eventum/eventum/blob/v3.0.3/.gitattributes

the keyword is `export-ignore`.